# .NET 5 An error occurred while starting the application. DirectoryNotFoundException

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, web-hosting, .net-5

I developed a Web API in C# using .NET 5, and it's working so well on my local machine, but on the server, it's not working. After using the detailed error, The error was that the Resources Folder does not exist on the server while it really exists and I am sure that I am publishing it with the project.

I contacted server support, they told me we cannot help you, The problem is with your project.
Any help is appreciated.

Startup.cs:

```
using HadeethScienceApi.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace HadeethScienceApi
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("EnableCORS", builder =>
                {
                    builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                       .AllowAnyHeader()
                       .AllowAnyMethod();
                });
            });

            services.AddControllers();

            services.Configure<FormOptions>(o => {
                o.ValueLengthLimit = int.MaxValue;
                o.MultipartBodyLengthLimit = int.MaxValue;
                o.MemoryBufferThreshold = int.MaxValue;
            });

            services.AddControllersWithViews()
            .AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
                options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore);

            services.AddDbContext<Hadeeth_Science_DBContext>(options =>
                    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("HadeethScienceDB")));

            var jwtSection = Configuration.GetSection("JWTSettings");
            services.Configure<JWTSettings>(jwtSection);

            //to validate the token which has been sent by clients
            var appSettings = jwtSection.Get<JWTSettings>();
            var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(appSettings.SecretKey);

            services.AddAuthentication(x =>
            {
                x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddJwtBearer(x =>
            {
                x.RequireHttpsMetadata = true;
                x.SaveToken = true;
                x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
                    ValidateIssuer = false,
                    ValidateAudience = false,
                    ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
                };
            });

            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "HadeethScienceApi", Version = "v1" });
            });
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseSwagger();
                app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "HadeethScienceApi v1"));
            }

            app.UseCors("EnableCORS");

            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
            {
                FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"Resources")),
                RequestPath = new PathString("/Resources")
            });

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });

            
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to resolve the problem, but when I delete the resources folder and use the wwwroot instead, the project run successfully

Answer (score 0):

This error means the

> h:\root....Resources

file **does not be published to the server along with your project**.

Try to find the file location and publish it.

Check the official tutorial to publish your project:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/publish-to-iis?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Unfortunately, I tried to publish the project with respect to the official tutorial and other tutorials but nothing worked. The resources folder does really exists in the project and the error is directory not found. Something very strange.